# One word for the phrase 'can be educated'

Tags: single-word-requests

For example as in someone is able to learn new things and get rid of his/her misconceptions in regard of social behaviour?

Comment: I think it's too obvious to warrant an 'answer' on ELU (and I'd downvote myself if I gave it as one): **teachable**.

Comment: *Corrigible*, *educable*, but these cover more than social behavior. *Socializable*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **maleable**
>
> 1:  Capable of being shaped or formed, as by hammering or pressure
>
> 2:  Easily controlled or influenced

In the case of social behavior, if the person were to learn on his own, maybe **adaptable** or **open-minded**

Comment: Adaptable is the word i was looking for,  thx.

Comment: Is that definition copied from an authoritative reference, like a dictionary? If it is, you must *visibly identify (state)* and also *link to* the source.  If it isn’t, you probably shouldn’t format it as if it were.